# .ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-* Permission denied

Tags: ansible

Remote host throws error while running Ansible playbook despite a user being sudo user.

```
"/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/ludd/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1466162346.37-16304304631529/zypper'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fix that worked for me, was to change the path of the ansible's `remote_tmp` directory, in ansible's configuration file, e.g.

```
# /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
remote_tmp      = /tmp/${USER}/ansible
```

Detailed information can be found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5725#issuecomment-45217363).

**Note:** With ansible **v4** (or later) this this variable might look like this `ansible_remote_tmp` check the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sh_shell.html#parameter-remote_tmp)

**Caution**：Ansible Configuration Settings can be declared and used in a configuration file which will be searched for in the following [order](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file):

- `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (environment variable if set)
- `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
- `~/.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
- `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

Changing `remote_tmp` didn't solve the issue for me. What *did* solve it, however, was removing `--connection=local` from the playbook invocation.

Comment: where is stored that variable?

Answer (score 1):

I had to set variable `ansible_remote_tmp` rather than `remote_tmp` in order to make it working.

Answer (score -3):

How does the file in question get to the host? Do you copy or sync it? If you do, may want do to do

```
chmod 775 fileName
```

on the file before you send it to the host.