# Permission denied using lineinfile with become:yes in Ansible task

Tags: ansible-2.x

```
TASK [ansible-role-domain-member : add local hostname to /etc/hosts] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.0.0.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.0.2 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618421785.04-66535-11992536214126/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 2}
```

Here is the task causing the error:

```
- name: add local hostname to /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    line: >
      {{ ansible_default_ipv4["address"] }} {{ ansible_hostname }}.{{ ansible_domain }} {{ ansible_hostname }}
    regexp: '^{{ ansible_default_ipv4["address"] }}'
  become: yes
  become_user: centos
```

- Ansible 2.10
- Other tasks in this role requiring root execute without issue using standard `become:yes`
- This has previously executed on other hosts without issue. The current host is the latest stable release of CentOS7.

Here is the full verbose output, including specifying Python3 as the interpreter in the playbook run command:

```
TASK [ansible-role-domain-member : add local hostname to /etc/hosts] ********************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/user/src-local/organization/ansible-role-domain-member/tasks/main.yml:10
<10.0.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 10.0.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~centos && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (0, '/home/centos\n', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<10.0.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 10.0.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/centos/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189="` echo /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189=/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189\n', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/text/formatters.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/distro/_distro.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/_collections_compat.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/compat/selectors.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/_text.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/parsing/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/validation.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/compat/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/_utils.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/parameters.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/distro/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/_json_compat.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/file.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/text/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/text/converters.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/pycompat24.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/parsing/convert_bool.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/collections.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/compat/_selectors2.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/six/__init__.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/sys_info.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/warnings.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/common/process.py
Including module_utils file ansible/module_utils/basic.py
Including module_utils file ansible/__init__.py
Using module file /Users/user/src-local/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/lineinfile.py
<10.0.0.2> PUT /Users/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-35965MzMlUe/tmpGOreh_ TO /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set sftp_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 '[10.0.0.2]'
<10.0.0.2> (0, 'sftp> put /Users/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-35965MzMlUe/tmpGOreh_ /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\n', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug2: Remote version: 3\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "posix-rename@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "statvfs@openssh.com" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "fstatvfs@openssh.com" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "hardlink@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension "fsync@openssh.com" revision 1\r\ndebug3: Sent message fd 8 T:16 I:1\r\ndebug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> /home/centos size 0\r\ndebug3: Looking up /Users/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-35965MzMlUe/tmpGOreh_\r\ndebug3: Sent message fd 8 T:17 I:2\r\ndebug3: Received stat reply T:101 I:2\r\ndebug1: Couldn\'t stat remote file: No such file or directory\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_OPEN I:3 P:/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:4 O:0 S:32768\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 4 32768 bytes at 0\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:5 O:32768 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:6 O:65536 S:32768\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_WRITE I:7 O:98304 S:23184\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 5 32768 bytes at 32768\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 6 32768 bytes at 65536\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: In write loop, ack for 7 23184 bytes at 98304\r\ndebug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_CLOSE I:4\r\ndebug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<10.0.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 10.0.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/ /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
<10.0.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 -tt 10.0.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (1, '\r\n{"msg": "The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: \'/etc/.ansible_tmpnr8YsGhosts\'", "failed": true, "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_maxSYK/ansible_lineinfile_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\\", line 2394, in atomic_move\\n    tmp_dest_fd, tmp_dest_name = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=b\'.ansible_tmp\', dir=b_dest_dir, suffix=b_suffix)\\n  File \\"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py\\", line 304, in mkstemp\\n    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)\\n  File \\"/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py\\", line 239, in _mkstemp_inner\\n    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)\\nOSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: \'/etc/.ansible_tmpnr8YsGhosts\'\\n", "invocation": {"module_args": {"unsafe_writes": false, "group": null, "insertbefore": null, "dest": "/etc/hosts", "selevel": null, "create": false, "seuser": null, "serole": null, "backrefs": false, "insertafter": null, "state": "present", "firstmatch": false, "mode": null, "path": "/etc/hosts", "owner": null, "regexp": "^10.0.0.2", "line": "10.0.0.2 shell.my.domain shell\\n", "attributes": null, "backup": false, "validate": null, "setype": null}}}\r\n', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\nShared connection to 10.0.0.2 closed.\r\n')
<10.0.0.2> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
Shared connection to 10.0.0.2 closed.
<10.0.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_password not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User="centos")
<10.0.0.2> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<10.0.0.2> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8)
<10.0.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/user/.ansible/cp/22eeb4c8d8 10.0.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1618426266.02-36125-64004255919189/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (0, '', 'OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.2 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 36026\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_maxSYK/ansible_lineinfile_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2394, in atomic_move
    tmp_dest_fd, tmp_dest_name = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=b'.ansible_tmp', dir=b_dest_dir, suffix=b_suffix)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 304, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 239, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/.ansible_tmpnr8YsGhosts'
fatal: [10.0.0.2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backrefs": false,
            "backup": false,
            "create": false,
            "dest": "/etc/hosts",
            "firstmatch": false,
            "group": null,
            "insertafter": null,
            "insertbefore": null,
            "line": "10.0.0.2 shell.my.domain shell\n",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/etc/hosts",
            "regexp": "^10.0.0.2",
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "state": "present",
            "unsafe_writes": false,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "The destination directory (/etc) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/.ansible_tmpnr8YsGhosts'"
}
```

Comment: `become: yes` doesn't necessarily means you become root, this depends on the configured `become_user` setup. And being part of a sudoer group that allows some super user commands does not necessarily means you have **full** super users' right on the node.

Comment: Did you try to run your playbook with `-vvvvv`, or add some non variable-dependent text to the `/etc/hosts` file? If your hosts are somehow different, maybe you should check if all Python modules are present, or change the interpreter to Python 3 using the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable somewhere.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I've tried become_user:root and become_user:centos with the same result. It seems to be an Ansible temporary file causing the issue: .ansible_tmpnr8YsGhosts

Comment: @StefanoMartins I've added verbose output above, and tried specifying Python3 as the interpreter (default on the host)

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I created an ansible.cfg file in my working directory and overrode the remote_tmp value to what's shown below, which resolved the issue.

```
# /Users/user/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
remote_tmp      = /tmp/${USER}/ansible
```

I still don't fully understand the nature of what's going on here, so if someone can provide more context I'd appreciate it.

Credit to [.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-* Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880491/ansible-tmp-ansible-tmp-permission-denied)